# Visual studio 2010 express error "Requested registry access is not allowed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I am using visual studio 2010 express C#.
When ever i try to create a new form or project, an error message pops "Requested registry access is not allowed".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it is a registry problem, when i open regedit and click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/VCSExpress.cs.10.0 it sais VCSExpress.csproj.10.0 cannot be opened. An error is preventing this key from being opened.
Details:Access is denied. But i also can't change the permitions there. In other keys in regedit, i can edit them. I have problem only on the VCSExpress registry entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio will sometimes try to update something in the registry that requires Administrator access (for example, when you register it).

Normally, running Visual Studio once as an admin will fix the problem, then you can go back to using an unprivileged user.

If that doesn't help, you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what it is doing.

**Update**

If you can't access the registry key as an Administrator, try taking ownership of it.  Assuming you're using Windows 7, run regedit as an Administrator, navigate to the key, right-click and select Permissions, click the Advanced button, go to the Owner tab and you can change the owner to Administrators.  Remember to select "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects".  You should then be able to access the registry key.

Comment: I actually had visual studio c# web developer 2010 edition in my computer installed but I couldn't create windows form applications, so I installed visual studio C# 2010 express for windows forms. 
When I opened visual studio c# web developer 2010 edition created a web form, closed it and opened the visual studio C# 2010 express for windows forms, the problem disappeared like magic. I am not sure what caused the problem, but everything seems to be ok. Weird problem though and I am not sure what was causing it.

Comment: The regisry keys are also enabled now and i can access them without access denied. Also your solution on the registry key gave me a good hint on what was going on, so I will accept your solution, thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Visual Studio 2010 as an administrator and see if that helps
Are you on a domain, or on some sort of locked down account?

Comment: I am the computer owner, and i am also under the administrator account

Answer (score 1):

Maybe opening it by right clicking and selecting "Run as administrator" solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2019

Close the visual studio and right click it and select **Run as administrator**.

It works..